# Haskell Hidden Packages: Data.HashSet

Tags: haskell, hashset, ghci

I'd like to use Data.HashSet in Haskell. So I put `import Data.HashSet` at the beginning of my program. GHCi complains: `Could not find module Data.HashSet`.

My questions are:

- How can I get Data.HashSet to work?
- I've read somewhere that this is part of a hidden module or package. Why is the module hidden? Does "hidden" mean that I should not use it?
- If I should not use it, is there a better alternative for a haskell data structure with a near-constant lookup time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Data.HashSet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unordered-containers/0.2.2.1/doc/html/Data-HashSet.html) is a module in the [unordered-containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers) package, and also in the [hashmap](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hashmap/1.3.0.1/doc/html/Data-HashSet.html) package. If you have either package installed,

```
import Data.HashSet
```

should work out of the box, since it is an exposed module of both packages. To install it (using `unordered-containers`, since that is the commonly used one),

```
cabal update
cabal install unordered-containers --dry-run
-- check that it wouldn't reinstall anything, if all's fine
cabal install unordered-containers
```